# Unexpectedly changing widget in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, widget

I have a xamarin forms app and a widget for Android platform in it.
The widget displays a calendar with highlited days according to the app's logic. It consists of a ListView filled with 7 TextViews text and color of which is made in-app. But I've encountered 2 annoying troubles:

1. trouble with sizing

During the development and launching the app on the emulator I made it look just like [I wanted to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beRor.png) But when I deployed it on my personal device I've met with [another result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdgDM.png) I guess the trouble is in different desktop cell size on different devices. The code of all .xml files is given below.

**widgetinfo.xml:**

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:minWidth="145dp"
                android:minHeight="110dp"
                android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
                android:resizeMode="horizontal"
                android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"/>
```

**list_row.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d1"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d2"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d3"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d4"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d5"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d6"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d7"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**widget_layout.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewWidget"
    android:choiceMode="none"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, the question - is there any way to make all the textviews look the same at all devices? I don't really need to change their size when resizing the widget, but such an option could also be really useful.

2. trouble with re-colouring.

when I press onto my widget (it always happens in random number of presses - sometimes it happens after the first one, sometimes - after about 20), or try to resize it, the colours [go mad and change without any logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/friGX.png).

I was trying to add breakpoints into the ListProvider - they just don't react. I thought the trouble is with some intent coming while interacting the widget, but OnRecieve method doesn't react too. I just can't understand what makes the widget to change the colours. Codes are also below.

**ListProvider.cs:**

```
        public class ListProvider : Java.Lang.Object, RemoteViewsService.IRemoteViewsFactory
{
    private List<ListItem> listItemList = new List<ListItem>();
    private List<CallbackMyWorks> works = new List<CallbackMyWorks>();
    private Context context;
    private int d;
    private int i;
    private int k;
    private DateTime dt;

    public ListProvider(Context contextNew)
    {
        context = contextNew;
        k = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month);
        i = 0;
        dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1);
        d = (int)dt.DayOfWeek;
        if (d == 0)
            d = 7;
        works = LoadFromFile();
        populateListItem();
    }

    public RemoteViews GetViewAt(int position)
    {
        RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.list_row);
        for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
        {
            FillList(remoteView, position, j);
        }
        return remoteView;
    }

    private void FillList(RemoteViews remoteView, int i, int j)
    {
        int res = 0;
        if (j == 0)
            res = Resource.Id.d1;
        else if (j == 1)
            res = Resource.Id.d2;
        else if (j == 2)
            res = Resource.Id.d3;
        else if (j == 3)
            res = Resource.Id.d4;
        else if (j == 4)
            res = Resource.Id.d5;
        else if (j == 5)
            res = Resource.Id.d6;
        else if (j == 6)
            res = Resource.Id.d7;
        remoteView.SetTextViewText(res, listItemList[i].days[j]);
        if ((i == 0 && int.Parse(listItemList[i].days[j]) > 7) || (i > 3 && int.Parse(listItemList[i].days[j]) < 15))
            remoteView.SetInt(res, "setBackgroundColor", Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
        else
        {
            if (listItemList[i].specs[j].Equals("1"))
            {
                remoteView.SetInt(res, "setBackgroundColor", Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(Preferences.Get("dayColor", "#bf3737")));
                remoteView.SetTextColor(res, Android.Graphics.Color.White);
            }
            else if (listItemList[i].specs[j].Equals("2"))
            {
                remoteView.SetInt(res, "setBackgroundColor", Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(Preferences.Get("nightColor", "#203080")));
                remoteView.SetTextColor(res, Android.Graphics.Color.White);
            }
            else if (listItemList[i].specs[j].Equals("8") | listItemList[i].specs[j].Equals("7") | listItemList[i].specs[j].Equals("4"))
            {
                remoteView.SetInt(res, "setBackgroundColor", Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(Preferences.Get("specColor", "#2f8254")));
                remoteView.SetTextColor(res, Android.Graphics.Color.White);
            }
            else if (listItemList[i].specs[j].Equals("О"))
            {
                remoteView.SetInt(res, "setBackgroundColor", Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(Preferences.Get("vacColor", "#FFE4C4")));
                remoteView.SetTextColor(res, Android.Graphics.Color.White);
            }
        }

    }

    private void populateListItem()
    {
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
        if (d != 1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < d - 1; j++)
            {
                listItem.days[j] = dt.AddDays(-1 * (d - j - 1)).Day.ToString();
            }
        }
        for (int j = d; j <= 7; j++)
        {
            i++;
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, i);
            var find = works.FirstOrDefault(x => x.getDate() == dt);
            if (find != null)
            {
                listItem.specs[j - 1] = find.getType();
            }
            else
                listItem.specs[j - 1] = "0";
            listItem.days[j - 1] = i.ToString();
        }
        listItemList.Add(listItem);
        for (int z = 0; z <= 4; z++)
        {
            AddFullWeek();
        }

    }

    private void AddFullWeek()
    {
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            i++;
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, i);
            var find = works.FirstOrDefault(x => x.getDate() == dt);
            if (find != null)
            {
                listItem.specs[j] = find.getType();
            }
            else
                listItem.specs[j] = "0";
            listItem.days[j] = i.ToString();
            if (i == k)
                i = 0;
        }
        listItemList.Add(listItem);
    }

    public int Count { get { return listItemList.Count; } }


    public long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }


    private int cellNum(int col)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public RemoteViews LoadingView { get { return null; } }

    public int ViewTypeCount { get { return 1; } }

    public bool HasStableIds { get { return true; } }


    public void OnCreate()
    {
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnDataSetChanged()
    {
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnDestroy()
    {
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    private List<CallbackMyWorks> LoadFromFile()
    {
        try
        {
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            string filePath = Path.Combine(path, "calPage.ods");
            string json;
            using (var file = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var strm = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                json = strm.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CallbackMyWorks>>(json);
        }
        catch (Exception) { return new List<CallbackMyWorks>(); }
    }
}
```

**WidgetProvider.cs:**

```
    [BroadcastReceiver(Label = "Календарь")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" })]
[MetaData("android.appwidget.provider", Resource = "@xml/widgetinfo")]
public class WidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider
{
    public override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        base.OnUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        int N = appWidgetIds.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context, appWidgetIds[i]);
            appWidgetManager.UpdateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
        }
    }

    private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context, int appWidgetId)
    {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.widget_layout);
        string PACKAGE_NAME = context.PackageName;
        Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(WidgetService));
        svcIntent.SetPackage(PACKAGE_NAME);
        svcIntent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetId, appWidgetId);
        svcIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(svcIntent.ToUri(IntentUriType.AndroidAppScheme)));
        remoteViews.SetRemoteAdapter(Resource.Id.listViewWidget, svcIntent);
        return remoteViews;
    }
}
```

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Could you please post the full code of `ListProvider.cs`?

Comment: And what's the `CallbackMyWorks` in your code?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT just a model class to interact with a server app.

`public class CallbackMyWorks
{
private string type;
private DateTime date;
public CallbackMyWorks(String type, DateTime date)
{
this.type = type;
this.date = date;
}
public String getType()
return type;
public void setType(String type)
this.type = type;
public DateTime getDate()
return date;
public void setDate(DateTime date)
this.date = date;
}`

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT the main trouble is that I can't understand which method exactly makes the widget to change colors. I've been trying, probably, all the methods described in learn.microsoft.com, but all of them are called **AFTER** colors are changed. Breakpoints in any point of ListProvider do nothing (but this is the only place in code where I interact colors). If I could realise what exactly method make colors change I think I managed this trouble.

Comment: You mean the color of the little squares? And what's the `days` and `specs` in class `ListProvider`? If it is convinient for you,could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT please, take a look: https://github.com/AlSeedius/WidgetDemo
For this moment I decided just to create 42 textviews and work with them. It's less comfortable, but it still works.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT so, is there any progress?